# Can you pause the game in Starbound?

Tags: starbound

I was playing Starbound single player, and had to step away from the computer for a while. I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> button and wandered away - a menu came up and so I assumed this had paused the game. When I returned, I was starving to death!

**Can you pause the game in Starbound? If so, how?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the Starbound forums there are several complaints about the lack of this very feature.  See a couple [here](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/hotkeys-and-a-pause.34803/) and [here](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/no-pause-on-single-player.35914/) (note the forums seem under a lot of stress at this time so you may have to reload a couple times).

It appears that as of this time in Beta Stage 1 - Progenitor on 12/7/13 there is no pause feature, but I was not able to find an official developer response to this.

UPDATE (5/11/14): It appears that this has still not been implemented in the game, but I looked for a work-around when a comment was made.  [This link](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/pause-please.78120/) led me to a suggestion that you always keep a chair around.  Apparently you do not get hungry while you are sitting (or apparently sleeping) so you can wall yourself in and just take a seat.  I put this to the test and it seems to work.

[image: before lunch]

I took this picture before going to lunch and ate up to full at 12:29PM (Sorry if that's not readable).  I made lunch for myself and ate and came back to see if my little Stitch was still doing alright.  I clicked the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to see how he was doing at 1:05pm and:

[image: after lunch]

Still full.  I left him a fire so as not to freeze to death, but with this chair and a few blocks I feel this could suffice for a pause-like feature.  You might also consider carrying a bed with you so you can not only not starve, but also heal.

Comment: What is the current state of pause functionality? I simply cannot play a game like this. I have to pause a game to do things now and then.

Comment: This still has not been implemented to my knowledge, but I did find information about a work-around that seems relatively pain-free and added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Download Process Hacker and suspend the game for later resuming. Tested.

http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/

EDIT: Sadly it doesn't work for longer than half an hour's suspending. Game quits with error.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of the Spacefarer update (1.3), the game now pauses when the menu is open. This change is for Single Player only.

> **Minor Changes / Bug Fixes**
>
> Gameplay now pauses while menu is open (single player only)
>
> Source: http://playstarbound.com/spacefarer-update/